# Unable to install Firebase iOS SDK (v3.2.0)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

I am unable to install Firebase iOS SDK (v3.2.0).
I followed instruction from Firebase but it will install legacy SDK v2.5.1

**Podfile looks like**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FireBaseTestApp' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

**Error**

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Core` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Core`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your **podfile** to

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'FireBaseTestApp' do

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'

end
```

Comment: According to new version of firebase you may need to add firebase pod whatever you want to use

target “Ramify” do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/AppIndexing'
    pod 'Firebase/Crash'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end